# trying to acknowledge basic facts about topology for beginner level...

Tags: general-topology

1.suppose there is a topology defined on some set X,let us call it tau.whether tau is finer than itself?
2.can we define a topology on empty set?
why or why not?

Comment: What does "finer" mean?

Comment: if two topologies are defined on a set.we say tau is finer than tau prime,if every open set in tau prime is open in tau

Answer (score 2):

$\tau\subseteq\tau$ and consequently $\tau$ is finer than itself. Of course we can define a topology on $X=\varnothing$. The only choice is $\tau=\{\varnothing\}$. Clearly $X,\varnothing\in\tau$ and if $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of sets in $\tau$, $A_n=\varnothing\;\forall\;n\implies\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\varnothing\in\tau$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^m A_n=\varnothing\in\tau$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Some texts explicitly demand a non-empty space (though this is not strictly necessary). An empty space (with its unique topology) is an initial object in the category Top, so this is sometimes handy to have.